# Is it possible to somehow write a def function in one file and use it in another if I import it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an 'toolkit' that will define many functions for me, and then import it when I need it... here is what I mean.

```
# I'm naming this file 'EssentialToolkit'
def hello():
   print ("Hello")
```

And in another file:

```
import EssentialToolKit
hello()
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vas71\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\tes.py", line 2, in <module>
hello()
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: you need to call it as `EssentialToolkit.hello()`. Or you could do `fromEssentialToolKit import hello` in order to be able to call it as just "plain" `hello()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other `Python` file does not know what `hello` is, you have to tell that you get it from `EssentialToolKit`

You can do as the following

```
import EssentialToolKit
EssentialToolKit.hello()
```

Or

```
from EssentialToolKit import hello
hello()
```